# Get UNIX converted time stamp for every day in a month in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

```
import time
i=1

while(i<=31):

    orginal_time=int(time.mktime(time.strptime('2017-11-i 12:00:00, '%Y-%m %d %H:%M:%S')))
    print(orginal_time)
    i=i+1
```

I can't figure out how to find the UNIX time stamp for every date in that month.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231789/how-to-get-all-days-in-current-month